# Thinking Sphinx - Globalize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx, globalize

I've set up Thinking Sphinx gem https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx
and I'm trying to get it work with globalize https://github.com/globalize/globalize gem.

I have a model named Content that has :name, :body ,:summary attributes and also has

```
translates :name, :body, :summary, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
```

for translations.
I've created a content_index that has

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :content, :with => :active_record do

  indexes translations.summary, :sortable => true
  indexes translations.body , :sortable => true

  where "content_translations.locale = 'my_locale'"  



end
```

When I do `rake ts:index` or `rake ts:rebuild` I get

> Generating configuration to
>   rails_app_path/config/development.sphinx.conf Sphinx
>   2.1.8-id64-release (rel21-r4675) Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc
>   (http://sphinxsearch.com)
>
> using config file 'rails_app_path/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
>   indexing index 'content_core'...
>
> collected 43 docs, 0.0 MB
>
> sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
>
> total 43 docs, 3266 bytes
>
> total 0.005 sec, 616808 bytes/sec, 8120.86 docs/sec
>
> skipping non-plain index 'content'...
>
> total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 1.3 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
>
> total 10 writes, 0.000 sec, 1.5 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
>
> rotating indices: successfully sent SIGHUP to searchd (pid=8282).

So when I get to rails console (rails c) and try something like

> Content.search "something"

I get empty results.

> 2.1.2 :050 > Content.search("something")
>
> Sphinx Query (0.6ms)  SELECT * FROM `content_core` WHERE
>   MATCH('something') AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0  LIMIT 0, 20
>
> Sphinx  Found 0 results
>
> => []

Does `skipping non-plain index 'content'...` line in `ts:rebuild` task has anything to do with it?

Comment: The 'skipping non-plain index' messages are completely normal (non-plain indexes can't be indexed). The 'something' you're searching for - is that in the translation columns? Or does Content itself have the same columns (given the fallbacks setting) and that's where the value is?

Comment: Thanks for your time. "something" is a word included in a text column of a translations record (the last record I created on testing purposes). It may be or maybe not included in the Content itself, in the examples I have tried it wasn't.

Comment: And 'something' is the actual phrase you're testing with? Or is it something else? In particular, is it something outside the standard ASCII characters? And with that in mind, which versions of Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx are you using? Older releases of both weren't quite UTF friendly by default.

Comment: No as a matter of fact its greek characters , with exact phrase being "και" (means 'and' in greek so its use in text bodies is very often). But I don't think thats the case , besides greek characters being in UTF-8 encoding ,I  also tested french (latin) characters as well. What I've forgotten to mention , is that the texts come in html_tags (because I commit them with ckeditor) but I've included in my config/thinking_sphinx.yml 'html_strip: true'. Do you think it could relate with it somehow?

Comment: Perhaps it's the html stripping, but html_strip should handle that fine... which versions of Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx are you using?

Comment: My sphinx version is 2.1.9 and thinking sphinx 3.1.1.

Comment: Right, both of those should allow for UTF by default. Can you fire up a mysql console that connects to Sphinx (`mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9306`) and run `SELECT * FROM content_core` to see what gets returned?

Comment: @pat
Well seems that I have missed something very basic here.
After running mysql --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9306 I got ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: Are you using Sphinx on a custom port? Is this testing happening locally, or on a remote machine?